# how do I parse a JSON file to SPLUNK?

Tags: json, splunk

I want to load a JSON file of evetlogs to be the source_type of SPLUNK.
how do I parse it to something I can perform searches on?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you can ingest the file, you can set the `KV_MODE=json` and the fields will be parsed properly. Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Automatickey-valuefieldextractionsatsearch-time

If you have already ingested the file, you can use `spath` to extract the fields properly. Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Spath . Use it as `index=* | spath output=out_field path=path_field`

You can also use the `spath` of the `eval` command. Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.6/SearchReference/TextFunctions#spath.28X.2CY.29 . You can use it as `index=* | eval f=spath(_raw, "foo.bah")`

Comment: fwiw - using multivalue commands on json properties is easier to read, and simpler to write, than spath

Comment: I can't ingest the file, 
it is very nested and also Splunk is breaking it in a way a cant extract fields with spath